# MySQL Date Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

any ideas of how to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT ip FROM clicks 
WHERE ip = ? 
AND SECOND(date_clicked)+4 > SECOND(NOW()) 
AND MINUTE(date_clicked) = MINUTE(NOW()) 
AND HOUR(date_clicked) = HOUR(NOW()) 
AND DATE(date_clicked) = DATE(NOW())
```

I mean, would be great to reduce number of DATE/TIME checks if possible. The main goal of that query is to see if click from specific IP did occur within 4 secs.

cheers,
/Marcin

Comment: It not only needs optimizing, but it doesn't work at all: if you're comparing 16:05:59 with 16:06:01, it doesn't match because the minute part is different.

Comment: thats why there is a minute part comparison, it works 100% but can be more efficient

Comment: No, it doesn't. `MINUTE( '16:05:59' ) != MINUTE( '16:06:01' )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one call to [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), to test if the stored date in `date_clicked` plus 4 seconds is greater than the current timestamp `(NOW())`.

```
SELECT 
  ip 
FROM clicks
WHERE ip = ?
  AND DATE_ADD(date_clicked, INTERVAL 4 SECOND) > NOW()
```

#### Update

I would just add that in practice this isn't going to work very well.  Many users share IP addresses. Under this system, two users on the same NAT address in a school or network wouldn't be able to click within 4 seconds of one another. It would be better to store some user-identifying value like a token from a session cookie or userid, than to store the IP and base the timeout on IP address.

Comment: great, thats what I am talking about :-)

Comment: yep, I know about it, but its to validate double-clicks only and will work well for that purpose